# Can Bluetooth mix input from guitar and send it to headphones?

Tags: practice, mixing

I want my smartphone mp3 player to mix a bluetooth input from guitar and send out to bluetooth headphones. If that's too difficult, just mix so I can hear on headphones. This is just for practice and I need it cheap and portable.

Comment: What do you mean by "bluetooth input from guitar"? Anyway, I don't think even these days the bluetooth latency got down to anything usable for playing musical instruments.

Comment: The delay was painful when I tried to do it with my PC as the middle man so to speak. I have seen small radios with male TRS connectors on them but I have not tried them.

Answer (score 11):

In short, no. Different sources give Bluetooth a minimum latency of 32 to 40 milliseconds that is very high for guitar. In practice the latency is usually much higher, and since you have two connections, that would double the latency again, and the mixer software on the phone would add some on top of that. Other complication is that the only kind of Bluetooth audio input phones support is headset mode, which means that you are forced to use a poor quality speech codec, and the phone would send the music back to the guitar, not to your headphones.

The most practical solution is a tiny headphone amplifier that plugs to the guitar, combined with wired headphones. There are models like Fender Mustang Micro that can receive a backing track over Bluetooth.

Answer (score 1):

Although not quite cheap (about CAD $500) I really like the Roland Waza-Air system. A very small radio transmitter plugs into your electric instrument, and the earphones pick up the signal with radio (unnoticeable latency). You can also send a bluetooth signal from your player to hear music to practise to. I have had so much fun with this (and I'm not in any way connected to the company). See https://www.boss.info/us/products/waza-air/

While the bluetooth music stream is somewhat latent, you don't notice because you are playing along in "real" time to the delayed stream.